# HTML body background image not cover all page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set background image to whole html page but I am failing everytime.It is not stretching.Here is my css and html codes:

**Css code:**

```
body {
    background-image:url(body_background.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width:1200px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#main_container_div {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 150px;
}

#div2 {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 600px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#div3 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 750px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Html body:**

```
<body>    
    <div id="main_container_div">
        <div id="div3">
        </div>
        <div id="div2">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

---

You can try with an image that has 1366x768 size. Also I am trying this on 1366x768 resolution.Note that the problem is visible on this or higher resolutions.Thanks for any help..

Comment: Would be helpful to see this code working **with** an image in a <http://jsfiddle.net>.

Comment: Sorry I dont know how to work in jsfiddle with a local png :( But I can give a link for image

http://i45.tinypic.com/w8npd3.png

Comment: You just need to add the HTML markup and the related CSS code to the windows on jsfiddle and link to your uploaded image. It's not hard, try it out. It will help you using this site and get you your answers faster and better.

Comment: Like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/mhmtsdtkrt/3AwHa/
But everything seems ok in jsfiddle result window.It does not show what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Try background-size: cover in your css

```
background-size:cover;
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use it in the body. Try it on the html element like so:

```
html
{
  background-image: url('your url');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height:100%;
}

<html>
  <!--bg is applied here instead -->
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and you can solve it either by stretching the image:

```
html{
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

or to keep the same proportions you can do:

```
body{
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachement: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
background: url(body_background.png) 100% 100% no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
background-size:cover;
```

does work but it doesn't support all the browser type.
Here's the code i used in the past,

```
section#background { 
    background: url('../img/background/feature.jpg') no-repeat center center; 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='img/background/feature.jpg',sizingMethod='scale'); 
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='img/background/feature.jpg',sizingMethod='scale')"; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover; 
    -moz-background-size: cover; 
    background-size: cover; }
```

and here's the jsfiddler link

http://jsfiddle.net/Raver0124/3AwHa/1/

Answer (score 0):

this usually works for me, as i usually do it in html instead of body.
this works as it takes the full page of the web browser. 
ps. i know this is old, thought it would help.

```
html { 
    background: url(images/bg.jpg or whatever link or img here) no-repeat center fixed; 
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved it by setting

```
height: auto
```

This way, if the content is bigger than the vertical screen, it will grow until it wraps it all. But you also must set

```
min-height: 100vh
```

So, the background will grow to occupy all the visible vertical screen if the content is smaller than it.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to display background in full page , you need to set background as repeat.

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

To

```
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

OR

```
background-repeat: repeat-y;
```

Comment: I think he wants the image to scale to the viewport and doesn't want it to repeat in any way.

Comment: Yes @kleinfreund is right.I dont want it to repeat.I want it to scale to whole page